# NSPredicate to filter out parent-child objects where a player owns none

Tags: objective-c, arrays, filtering, nspredicate

I have an array of groups.  Each group has a basic make-up of this;

```
Group {
  Name : NSString
  Children : NSArray
}
```

Each child within the children array can be owned by a certain Player

So ie;

```
Child1.owner = PlayerA
```

A player can only ever own 1 child item in a given group.

The problem I'm having is I need to write a `NSPredicate` to do the following.

Give me a list of all groups where Player A does not own any children.

I'm thinking that because a player can only ever purchase something once in a given group that I should move the array of owners up to groups, it might make it easier.

Anyway, if someone can point me in the direction of how to filter it on sub-children and then use this information to filter out groups where player A is not involved.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the snippet of the code. I have created a dummy array to simulate filtering.

```
NSDictionary *obj1 = @{@"name":@"name1", @"children":@[@{@"owner": @"owner1"}, @{@"owner": @"owner2"}]};
NSDictionary *obj2 = @{@"name":@"name2", @"children":@[@{@"owner": @"owner1"}, @{@"owner": @"owner2"}, @{@"owner": @"owner3"}]};
NSDictionary *obj3 = @{@"name":@"name3", @"children":@[@{@"owner": @"owner1"}]};
NSArray *totalObj = @[obj1, obj2, obj3];

NSString *reqdOwner = @"owner2";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"not children.owner contains %@", reqdOwner];
NSArray *filtered = [totalObj filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Your answer works for the dictionary. I will need to customize it for my custom objects, but I will accept.